# RenderPartialForEach<T>(..) HtmlHelper for asp.net mvc?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

This throws error:

```
public static void RenderPartialForEach<T>
(this HtmlHelper helper, string partialName, IList<T> list)
{
    foreach (var item in list)
       helper.RenderPartial(partialName, item);
}
```

=>

> Error Message: CS1519: Invalid token '(' in class, struct, or interface member declaration
>
> Line 283:            #line default
> Line 284:            #line hidden
> Line 285:            @__w.Write("\r\n    \r\n\r\n\r\n");
> Line 286:        }
> Line 287:

Is it possible to create clean htmlhelper
which is able to render partial views for every item in list passing it as model?

**Edit:**
That was just a blunder from my side. I forgot to add '<% } %>'.
And got confused cause of error message. ^^

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to declare the method in a class.  It's not obvious that you are doing that, but it would certainly cause the type of error that you are seeing.

```
  public static class CustomHtmlHelperExtensions
  {
       public static void RenderPartialForEach<T>(
              this HtmlHelper helper,
              ...
  }
```

**EDIT**: In retrospect, given the text of the error, I suspect that the error lies elsewhere in your markup.  Perhaps, you're missing a parenthesis around an if statement or foreach clause.

Comment: Actually, i deleted my question already - but then reopened just to mark your answer as accepted. Quite amazing one (cause of info provided).

Answer (score 1):

Where are you declaring such a thing? Try writing that extension method in a separate static class in a code file, not inline in `.aspx`.

Comment: The error message looks like a problem in `.aspx`, not in code. How are you calling it?

Answer (score 0):

Just a guess... you are implementing a generic method (of T) but you are not actually replacing the generic parameter (T) with a type argument?

Comment: Nope... it's not so bad with me. Actually - it seems that error is somewhere else and cause of vagueness of error message i got confused completely.